# Not getting reputation points for up votes on SO today for some reason. What's up?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Today I've been given a number of up votes on answers, but when I never receive reputation for them, and when I click on my mail icon right by my name I can see the answers with a 1 in a green box, like the others, but with no reputation points in the center.

Bug?

What should I do?

**UPDATE**  Another odd thing:  If I click the mail icon it says I've only achieved 35 points.  However, If I click on the "Today" link, then it shows that I've earned 203 rep!

**UPDATE**  The rep from the today link is correct.  I understand that I've capped for the day.  However, there still remains the issue that clicking on the mail icon is not reporting the correct reputation, up votes, etc.

Comment: The 203 most certainly **is** correct... for server-time ;-p

Comment: Only a few more hours until tomorrow (server-time)

Comment: I think you are just trying to brag about hitting the cap.  I'll give ya a pat on the back!!

Comment: @Marc not considering the fact that it's been giving me rep today until around 2 pm, though.  Something is definitely wrong guys, trust me.  I started this morning with 0 rep, and got up to 35, after that, nothing.  I wish I could show you what I'm seeing on my screen.  It looks really odd.

Comment: The time zones can be tricky, but they are correct. You have to be careful what you're looking at for reference.

Comment: You're in Miami which makes you -4 GMT if I recall correctly, so the day is really 8pm Yesterday - 8pm today for you, local time.

Comment: Wait three more hours, then you will start getting some more rep.

Comment: 2 1/4 hours   ​

Comment: This is what you're going after now http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1459/clicking-envelope-beside-username-shows-fewer-recent-activities-than-today-butt

Comment: Thanks everyone for their input.  Now at least I know to make sure and use the Today link!

Comment: Dupe of 1459.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default "envelope" page isn't the same as the "today" page - it covers a smaller time period.

(If someone has a definition of what time period it covers, I'd be interested to know - it does seem to behave rather oddly at times.)

Comment: That's exactly the information I'm looking for, because up until now I had no idea the envelope page was any different from the today page.  I still don't understand why there's a discrepancy between the two.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone has **ever** figured out the time period of the envelope. I think it is like the badges... you're meant to guess ;-p

Comment: It seems to me that the default is capturing "today" based on my local time. That's just what it seems to me, could be completely wrong.

Comment: @Yshuditelu, I think it's *server* local time, SO has no way of knowing *your* local time

Comment: I've always believed it to be server local time, based on a few observations.

Answer (score 4):

You've hit the reputation cap of 200 rep in a single day.

The day starts at 12am UTC, using Jon Skeet's great [reputation tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?so=69979&sf=&su=&meta=&mode=today) you can track this more easily. You're currently at 203 reputation for the day.

Comment: No, I've tallied only 35 reputation today.

Comment: But you know what, I just found something that hints to the same issue!  I'm updating my question.

Comment: Jon's rep tracker disagrees with you. You may not be taking the time zone into consideration, or you could be relying on the data from the envelope which has it's own time related quirks regarding reputation.

Comment: @Ian Yeah I'm inclined to agree as well, but I still get the wrong report one way or the other when I click on the mail icon.

Answer (score 3):

You have accumulated [203 points today](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?so=69979&sf=&su=&meta=&mode=today&showzero=true&showflair=true). Beyond that, only accepted answers (+15) and bounties count. And downvotes ;-p

Comment: Thanks Marc.  Unfortunately I know about the rep cap already, and that's not the problem.  I've only been given 5 upvotes and 1 accepted answer today!

Comment: Two independent rep trackers disagree with you... I'm inclined to believe them. What makes you think you only have 5 upvotes (etc)? Contrasted to what the system says you have?

Comment: Perhaps the bug is not in the actual reputation earned, but what the is reported when I click on the mail icon.  When I click on the mail icon I see the following: ...

Comment: Showing 2009-08-20 to 2009-08-20 ; current time is 2009-08-20 21:40:51 UTC - 35 rep earned 5 upvotes 1 accepted.  However, when I click on today I get: Showing 2009-08-20 to 2009-08-20 ; current time is 2009-08-20 21:42:25 UTC 203 rep earned more upvotes etc.

Comment: The today link is what is important when checking how close you are to the cap.

Comment: @Ian Maybe so, but if the today link is what is important then why not make the envelope link go straight to the today report?  That's what I want to know, not some unknown timespan that everyone is guessing at.

Answer (score 2):

From the FAQ:

> You can earn up to 200 reputation per day, but no more.

It's a good thing, it means you won the game today.  Good luck tomorrow!

[Marc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15922/not-getting-reputation-points-for-up-votes-on-so-today-for-some-reason-whats-u/15926#15926) and [Ian](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15922/not-getting-reputation-points-for-up-votes-on-so-today-for-some-reason-whats-u/15923#15923) both point to how they know that.

Comment: Actually, I also know from here - but I don't think most people have access to that... http://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/69979?StartDate=2009-08-20&EndDate=2009-08-20

Comment: Cheater `:P`

Answer (score -4):

You are hitting the cap, but you don't think so because the recent activity page is using a different timezone than you would think to determine what has been done 'today'.

This is not a **bug**, this is a **feature**.

Comment: So the bug is that the mail icon is using a different timespan than the today link?

Comment: It's not a bug, just a quirk

Comment: **YES**, for the love of God, **YES**.

Comment: @Ian: It is not a **bug**, it is a **feature**.

Comment: @Rich both the mail icon and the today link report the same time span.  Yet they show different results.  Nothing is displayed to the user to indicate that one is based on the server and the other is based from my location.  I'm not disagreeing with you about that I just don't understand how this isn't a bug?

Comment: WHOOOOOOOOSH.

Comment: @Ian I'm not even sure how to process that.  In my opinion: It doesn't work as I expect it to work, therefore it is a defect.  Maybe no one agrees with the expectation that I have, but that's my expectation of that feature.

Comment: BTW, I happen to have the same opinion as Jon on this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1459/clicking-envelope-beside-username-shows-fewer-recent-activities-than-today-butt/1462#1462

Comment: @Joseph: Jokes.  Get them.

Comment: I can't stop facepalming...