# Lags on updating scores and reputations and recent information?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Has anyone else noticed that there are sometimes lags in the aggregate computations?  I was switching (fairly fast) between my recent scores screen  on SO and the question (because the answers were flying in thick and fast), and noticed that the summary screen didn't reflect all the points I'd earned according to the question pages, nor did the score at the top of the page?

I'm going to guess that it is some sort of optimization, or possibly related to load balancing and distributing the information.  It is disconcerting, but not a long term problem; it seems to take minutes at most (and more nearly seconds) to sort itself out.

Is there anything that can be done to smooth it out?

A variant on this problem - I'm not clear whether the recent scoring is a 'last 24 hours ending now' or 'the last day from 00:00 UTC to now'.  Does the daily limit apply to a fixed interval (like 00:00 UTC to 24:00 UTC on the day) or is it also a rolling limit?

Another minor variant on the issue - summary says "170 points"; scoring in detail says 3 votes scored zilch (because I've reached 200 for the day).  I'd like to have accuracy on all that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default screen is the <strike>last 24 hours</strike> hours since 12 on the local server.(someone verify,  I might be wrong, even jon and richie seemed a bit confused in their answers to the questions below).

If you click 'today', you will get the current info for the current UTC day. Yesterday will be the previous UTC day. The 200 rep limit applies to a UTC day.

See also:

- [Not getting reputation points for up votes on SO today for some reason. What's up?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15922/not-getting-reputation-points-for-up-votes-on-so-today-for-some-reason-whats-u/15929#15929) (richie's answer to similar concern)
- **https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1459/clicking-envelope-beside-username-shows-fewer-recent-activities-than-today-butt/1462#1462 (jon skeet's responce, even he was not completely sure)**

Comment: Bah, where is that other similar question....